# sed - or another tool for regex text replacement

Tags: regex, sed, replace

I need to replace all `$arr[key]` with `$arr['key']` but not `$arr[$key]` or `$arr[CONST]` or already rewritten as `$arr['key']`

Eventually `$arr[key]` with `{$arr['key']}`

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know to write *dynamic* substitutions and all these exclusions. Also I forgot to add another exclusion, those already in the form of `$arr['key']`. I'm trying to fix some issues to get to PHP 5.3. I've used `sed -e 's/<?=/<?php echo /g'` and a couple more to fix short tags, but replacements are not my strong and I have to do this over couple hundreds of files. I'm still trying meanwhile to write it on my own.. but thought someone could write it better and in a shorter time. Thanks for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
perl -pe 's/(\$\w+\[\s*)(?![A-Z\d]+\b)(\w+)(\s*])/$1\'$2\'$3/g' file.php
```

Example:

```
echo $arr[foo] $arr['ok'] $arr[3] $arr[CAPS] $arr[$var] $arr[ bar ] | perl -pe "s/(\$\w+\[\s*)(?![A-Z\d]+\b)(\w+)(\s*])/$1'$2'$3/g"
$arr['foo'] $arr['ok'] $arr[3] $arr[CAPS] $arr[$var] $arr[ 'bar' ]
```

Comment: `[root@vm X]# echo $arr[foo] $arr['ok'] $arr[3] $arr[CAPS] $arr[$var] $arr[ bar ] | perl -pe "s/(\$\w+\[\s*)(?![A-Z\d]+\b)(\w+)(\s*])/$1'$2'$3/g" -bash: ![A-Z\d]+\b: event not found`

Comment: @Andi, use proper quoting for your shell. My example was on windows. Try the line above it.

Comment: `echo '$arr[foo] $arr[''ok''] $arr[3] $arr[CAPS] $arr[$var] $arr[ bar ]'` works fine in bash. quoting single and double quotes sucks in any shell. ;-)

Comment: I have to escape the ! because of shell. I still get ` echo '$arr[foo] $arr["ok"] $arr[3] $arr[CAPS] $arr[$var] $arr[ bar ]' | perl -pe "s/(\$\w+\[\s*)(?\![A-Z\d]+\b)(\w+)(\s*])/$1'$2'$3/g"
$arr[foo] $arr["ok"] $arr[3] $arr[CAPS] $arr[$var] $arr[ bar ]`

Comment: Also, when testing on files you actually care about, I recommend you use `perl -pi.bak -e ` to call your replacement. That way if it goes crazy you have file.php.bak to put back.

Comment: Here's the whole thing to test with in bash: `echo '$arr[foo] $arr[''ok''] $arr[3] $arr[CAPS] $arr[$var] $arr[ bar ] ' |  perl -pe 's/(\$\w+\[\s*)(?![A-Z\d]+\b)(\w+)(\s*])/$1''$2''$3/g'`